# Need to parse String in XML format to obtain Request Information 

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have got a String request in the XML format , which i need to parse it to obtain the Request data from it .
The XML  String would be conssiting of a lot of subtags within it , and data is appended in it in the form of CDATA as well as there are  >&lt  , ini t.
I want to use STAX approach for this .

Please sugesst if theer are any cons wtth this ??

i need this inside a Java Webservice

Comment: You may write a simple helper class to accomplish your task around DOM. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346867/851432

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your XML file with native PHP function.
EX :

```
$path = '/my/file/xml.xml';
$file = file_get_contents($path);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
```

And get nodes with :

```
$value1 = $xml->node[0]->value;
$value2 = $xml->node[1]->value;
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention , i need this inside a Java Webservice ( SO PHP isn't a option ) i am modfying my question also

Answer (score 0):

There would not be any issues in using DOM parser based STAX API.

Comment: Thanks Bala , we may have a huge xml for reading , so i am planning to go for STAX , instead of DOM . But unfortunately i couldn't find any examples related to paring XML String using STAX .